# Why urgent mission to fight Army of Dead and Wight hunting with bunch of people?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones S07E05, after receiving a message from Bran, Tyrion suggests Daenerys and Jon to bring a Wight to King's Landing in order to prove that the Army of the Dead and the White Walkers are real.

**For Jon**

Bran's message mentioned that there is an Army of Dead at Eastwatch (not few dead people walking around) and Jon has previously seen a big army at Hardhome. Considering both facts, it seems more logical for Jon and the group to wait and prepare combined force of North and Daenerys to fight Night's King with full capacity. What is strategic move behind going to the north of the wall with 7 brave people and risking their lives in order to convince Cersei?

Comment: What's your question? Seems like a scatter-brain, general rant about how their plan isn't a good one, with a "Why" attached.

Comment: In politics, like a game of chess you have to play every move in your mind before playing it on the game board. And you have to think about the amount of risk vs. outcome. For each and every previous move by Daenerys, Tyrion and Jon I am totally convinced of risk and outcome, but this move has more risk than the outcome. So, I wanted to know what people think about it, whether it's right or wrong, and if right, there is any justification. @MarkoStanojevic did a nice job with that.

Comment: `I wanted to know what people think about it, whether it's right or wrong` This site isn't for opinionated discussions, consult the [help center](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) if you want some help on what type of question you should avoid, and how to edit or construct your questions to be received better.

Comment: According to Help Center link, a question is appropriate which `insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references` and `inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”`. That is how the question has been asked and answered.

Comment: Related [scifi.se] question [What do Jon Snow and the party really hope to gain?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/167800/21267)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though it is said they need Wight for Cersei, the true reason is that they need it for everyone really. As time goes by more and more people are starting to accept it as a real threat, but only those who survived the Others understand the true danger. Daenerys kind of wants to listen to Jon after a while, but abandoning the war because of the legend of White Walkers is not the move she will make without this proof either. If she (or anyone else) really believed him and comprehend what kind of danger is actually coming, she would head for the Wall without wasting a minute.

So when they arrive at Eastwatch, Tormund asks Jon which queen he needs to convince, Jon replies: "Both". I think that is the heart of the matter. Furthermore, as Sam said, Citadel can make a large movement of armies, resources, and information if they would believe Others are coming. Other big or lesser lords and people, in general, may come around with news of such proof.

**For Jon**: he knows he won't succeed in defending the Wall with small numbers he has. He needs Daenerys first since she has more than 100k soldiers and has dragons, but he needs all Westeros really.

**For Daenerys and Tyrion**: they need to suspend a war with Cersei first as Daenerys won't go north since the war for the throne is more important to her. Tyrion knows Cersei also wants to get some time after the last defeat, so there is a chance. But as Jon said, even Tyrion doesn't really believe in Night King, so bringing Wight to the south will surely be very beneficial.

And no, it is not less risky to simply go with dragons to the Wall. There are many similar questions around like she just flies over with dragon and burns the Others. Truth is, Night King is too smart for that, plus he obviously has some magic powers. And we don't know what kind of aces he may keep hidden, millions of soldiers, giants, he can bring a horrible storm that will put down even dragons, etc. So, as lieutenant Stansfield in "Leon, the Professional" said: "Bring me everyone. EVERYONE!!!!!"

Answer (score 1):

> Why should they risk the life of brave people in order to convince
>   Cersei?

Because if the wights manage to break the wall and advance further, then everyone will die including people in Westeros, Dragonstone and in the Stark kingdom.

> And even if they succeed what is a guarantee that Cersei will agree to
>   fight Night's King alongside Daenerys and Jon?

This is GoT. So, one can't really speak for sure what will happen. And this is the reason why Tyrion tried to convince Jamie, who he rightly thinks would be the best person to convince the Queen of Westeros, Cersei Lannister.

> shouldn't Jon and the group wait and prepare combined force of North
>   and Daenerys and fight Night's King with full capacity?

Even Daenerys isn't fully convinced about the wights for sending her entire army and risk Dragonstone. If Cersei isn't convinced, and if Daenerys left Dragon stone to fight for Jon Snow, then Dragonstone would be an easy target to invade for Cersei. And this is exactly Tyrion asked Jon to get a wight so that they can convince Cersei to fight along with them against the wights.

> Isn't it less risky to go to Eastwatch with dragon/dragons and fight
>   the Army of Dead, as it has been known to Jon that wights are
>   susceptible to fire?

Again. Daenerys is not fully convinced about the wights to send all three of her babies beyond the wall. Also, there is no clear evidence of even her being able to control Viserion and Rhaegal. So, lending them to Jon and co. isn't a great idea either.

> And isn't it a wise move to finish the war with either Cersei or
>   Night's King first and then deal with another later, rather than
>   convincing one enemy to help to fight with another?

Not possible. None of the either would be waiting for the war with the other to finish.  Reason being that Cersei doesn't believe in the wights and would definitely look to take over Dragonstone with the slightest opportunity. And the wights are closer than ever to the wall, and Jon don't really have a lot of time on his hands for waiting.